# Cannot double-click on the call stack in VSCode during debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am debugging a code and when I try to double click on a line inside the "call stack" section, nothing happens. I expect a window popping up showing details.

The `launch.json` I am using is:

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch program",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build-tests/${input:p1}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
        "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "p1",
            "description": "What Unit Tests do you want to run?",
            "options": [
                "test/unit_tests/my-test"
            ],
            "default": "test/unit_tests/my-test",
            "type": "pickString"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: using VSCode 1.78.0 and C/C++ Intellisense, debugging extension

Comment: *include version info for the extensions too. sorry. I should have been more clear in my wording. and please [edit] it into the post.